# Umbraco why dropdown save prevalue

Tags: umbraco

Ok,

Hi guys, I am new to Umbraco and programming field, and as the title said its pretty straightforward, why umbraco dropdown save prevalue instead of the value instead? For example, I created a dropdown of Option A, and Option B but its being saved as number instead?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the prevalue could be edited in the back office at any time, so it saves the ID, as that can never change.

Note: the id of the revalue is saved in the database, but in the content cache, the actual value is used.

Comment: Alright, so whenever you change values from dropdown under developer tab, this will reflect as well to all pages using this datatype, is that the purpose?